# signal listener subclassed from CIlistener

Tags: omnet++

I have a signal produced from a module. I want to define a signal listener class in another module but whenever I want to subclass it from CIListener, it says it cannot make a new instance from my subclassed listener because the CIListener class is a pure virtual class (interface class). But I have re-declared or redefined all the pure virtual methods in my listener class. Instead when I user CListener class to subclass my listener it works! Do I have to subclass from CIListener?

Comment: could you amend your question with a [minimal test case](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you *believe* that you have re-defined all pure methods, but in fact the compiler thinks otherwise. There are 7 pure virtual methods that should be implemented with the proper signatures. If you want to support only certain data types (as it is in most cases) I would suggest to implement (extend) the `cListener` as it is just a NOP implementation of the `cIListener` interface (with all its methods throwing a datatype not supported error). Be sure to see whether you indeed override the necessary methods. You may use the `override` C++ keyword in your method definition.